# Angular 6 : How to identify forkJoin response

Tags: angular, rxjs

Angular 6 : How to identify response of api with **forkJoin**

```
reqs = [];
if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
   reqs.push(this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest))
}
if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
   reqs.push(this.customerService.updateAddress(addressUpdateRequest))
}

forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(result => {
   console.log('result :', result);
  //How to know response is from updatePhone and response from updateAddress?
});
```

How to can i identify response received is belong to updatePhone and updateAddress? based on identification i need to show message to user.

this both api returning 
**Array(2) >**

**{model:true, code:200, message:null},**

**{model:true, code:200, message:null}**

Comment: `forkJoin` preserves order so the array of results will be ordered the same way you listed the source Observables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap your reponses in another object that identifies their type by using the `map` pipe after each request. Just like this:

```js
reqs = [];
if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
    reqs.push(this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest)
        .pipe(map(value => ({type: 'phone', value: value})))
        .pipe(catchError(value => of({type: 'phone', failed: true}))))
}
if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
    reqs.push(this.customerService.updateAddress(addressUpdateRequest)
        .pipe(map(value => ({type: 'address', value: value})))
        .pipe(catchError(value => of({type: 'address', failed: true}))))
}

forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(results => {
    console.log('result :', results);

    for(let result of results){
        if(result.type == 'phone'){
            if(result.failed)
                console.log("Phone failed");
            else
                console.log("Phone: " + result.value);
        }

        else if(result.type == 'address'){
            if(result.failed)
                console.log("Address failed");
            else
                console.log("Address: " + result.value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The pipe with adding the type is unnecessary when using the `forkJoin` operator as the values are in order based on the array of observables.

Comment: That is right, but he is conditionally adding the observables to the array, so you wouldn't know which requests are actually part of the forkJoin. Is it [Phone], [Address], [Phone, Address] or even []

Comment: @ggrading you are right. i am not sure which is going to execute, its depending upon condition and there might case where either one of them is failing.

Comment: It still isn't necessary, but will probably make the code easier to extend in the future if there are other updates. Otherwise you can easily look at the size of the results and the `shouldUpdatePhone`/`shouldUpdateAddress` variables to know what the request was.

Comment: That would make the subscribe function impure, as he accesses a state outside of the function. Imagine those two booleans were properties that change between firing the requests and receiving the responses.

Comment: even i know shouldUpdatePhone/shouldUpdateAddress is true will not help as there might possible that something went wrong with backend and one of the api failed. In this case I wouldn't know which got failed and which successes.

Comment: @ggradnig... You can create a local variable that keeps the value scoped in the closure `const shouldUpdatePhone = ...code here to keep it scoped` It can change all it wants outside of this invocation and would have no issues.

Comment: Right, but what if the forkJoin Observable were to be returned by the function and subscribed to multiple times later. The point is, why would you not keep everything in the Observable pipe, but rely on an outside state? This just makes the code not reusable.. Okay, let's say the code is what it is in that snippet, would your suggestion really decrease the complexity?

Comment: @ggradnig your answer works for me :) . Just to know how can that work with error handling. if one api fails how can i get to know which is failing.

Comment: I would suggest to make use of the `catchError` operator. I've edited my post to include the error handling

Comment: @ggradnig but it isn't and multiple subscriptions wouldn't create a problem... not going to get into a lengthy debate. Here is an example to just show that it isn't necessary https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axrbvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel you are right, creating a function that has a closed scope solves the issue with modification of the variables. Both solutions are correct and valid, it is just a debate about which one is the cleaner solution. In the above snippet, it doesn't make a difference. If the Observable were to be reused somehow, you would face these issues: 1) The booleans would have to be returned by the function as well, 2) You couldn't easily modify the emissions with other pure pipes without also passing the booleans

Comment: @ggradnig if one api fails and other passes, I am just getting exception and NOT getting success for other api.. any idea why?

Comment: nvm that was my fault. thx @ggradnig :) its working as expected.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel What if there are more than 2 requests in the forkJoin using your solution ? Your conditions inside the `subscribe` would become messy as long as you would have to make conditions bigger and bigger to test every previous `shouldUpdateSmth`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(([phone, address]) => {
   if (!shouldUpdatePhone) {
     address = phone;
   }
});
```

<strike>But I think you are overseeing something, `forkJoin` emits an array of responses from all inner observables, once they are all completed. So it will only emit once, containing both responses (if they were both added to the array)</strike>

another option would be to add a pipe to the forkJoin and the inner subs
(untested code):

```
const reqs = [];
if (shouldUpdatePhone) {
   reqs.push(this.customerService.updatePhone(phoneUpdateRequest)).pipe(
     map((response) => ({ phone: response }))
   );
}
if (shouldUpdateAddress) {
   reqs.push(this.customerService.updateAddress(addressUpdateRequest)).pipe(
     map((response) => ({ address: response }))
   );
}

forkJoin(reqs).pipe(
  map((responses) => reponses.reduce((a, b) => ({...a, ...b}), {}))
).subscribe(result => {
   // result.address;
   // result.phone;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [RxJS documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin):

> `forkJoin` will wait for all passed Observables to complete and then it will emit an array with last values from corresponding Observables. So if you pass `n` Observables to the operator, resulting array will have `n` values, where first value is the last thing emitted by the first Observable, second value is the last thing emitted by the second Observable and so on.

Therefore, your `result` value should be an array with the first value being the response of the `updatePhone(...)` observable and the second value is the response from the `updateAddress(...)` observable.